# bannerslider in magento2 admin not working for my local?

Tags: magento2

I have installed bannerslider extension in my local ( in /htdocs/magento2/), but i am not getting in admin panel ,any one plz guide me for this problem ?

Comment: you have to check this post for your answer.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93322/bannerslider-in-magento2-admin-not-working-for-my-local

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got it from Magento Connect but it's not up to date because it's still in development.

Try getting the module from github https://github.com/Magestore/Bannerslider-Magento2, it worked for me.

If you have to extend it, don't forget to activate developer mode (php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer).

Comment: thankyou  thomas , its working fine now

Comment: i want to add slider image in admin, but slider is  not saving , its showing loading ?its taking toooo much time . is there any code error? plz help me out

Comment: I had the same issue and had to load this command on my magento root : php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer && php bin/magento cache:clean